# Find conditional expectation of two normally distributed variables given correlation coefficient

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

$X \sim N(0,\sigma_x^2)$ and $Y \sim N(0, \sigma_y^2)$, $\rho(X,Y) = \rho$. Find E[X|Y].

Attempt to the solution:
Firstly, I tried to use that $cov(X,Y) = \rho_{XY}\sigma_x\sigma_y = cov(Y, E[X|Y])$, but I didnt manage to find something meaninful.
Then I tried to use the definition $E[X|Y]:=\int{  {{f_{XY}(x,y)}\over{_{Y}(y)}}}$, but I am struggling with finding the joint distribution of X and Y. What can I do?

Comment: I doubt if $E(X|Y)$ can be determined without assuming that joint distribution is normal.

Comment: but it may not be normal, as far as I understand. Am I right? I supposed that we can find joint distribution if we know basic distributions and correlation. It seems pretty plausible to me.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: The joint distribution may not be normal and my suspicion is that the problem is ill-posed.

Comment: @EkeshKumar well, I think, no, if $\rho$ is not equal zero.

Comment: @KaboMurphy and if the joint distribution is normal, then we can just calculate it using an integral equation, which I have written previously?

Comment: There is not need to write down joint density. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal then $cov (X-cY,Y)=0$ when $c=\frac {EXY} {EY^{2}}=\frac {\rho} {\sigma_y^{2}}$. This implies that $X-cY$ and $Y$ are independent (since they have a joint normal distribution). Hence $E(X|Y)=E(X-cY|Y)+cE(Y|Y)=0+cY=cY$.

Comment: Thank you, maybe it was supposed that they are jointly normal.